# if class is 'current', then do this

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have this little hover script.

```
$('iframe').hover(function() {
    $('.caption').fadeIn(800);
},
function() {
    $('.caption').fadeOut(800);
});
```

When I hover over an iframe it fades in the class 'caption'.  When I exit the hover, it fades it out.  Simple enough.

I am using a plugin that adds a class 'current' to the current panel that is in view.  How can I add to this code so this effect ONLY happens IF the panel has a class 'current'.

Thanks!

Comment: Which panel? Have you tried a combined selector, e.g. `$(.caption.active')`, or `$(this).hasClass('active')`?

Comment: This can be done with CSS ( `:hover` + `opacity` + `transition:` ). No need for JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery is method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like so:

```
$('iframe').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).is('.current')) {
        $('.caption').fadeIn(800);
    }
},
function() {
    if ($(this).is('.current')) {
        $('.caption').fadeOut(800);
    }
});
```

Or alternatively, if you only wish to target `.caption` elements that are descendents of `.current` (if the iframe isn't the 'panel' with the current css class):

```
$('iframe').hover(function() {
    $('.current').find('.caption').fadeIn(800);
},
function() {
    $('.current').find('.caption').fadeOut(800);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I needed to only target the div with a class of current.  This worked perfectly.  I see how the .find mot hod works now.  Thank you!